# Unzip a large file and break into chunks in Google Cloud Storage Python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, blob, shutil, python-zipfile

I have a large zipped file in Google Cloud Storage. It needs to be unzipped and broken into smaller chunks to be uploaded to the same bucket. My memory limit is 2GB and the file is larger than that, so I cannot unzip it all at once. [shutil.copyfileobj](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj)(fsrc, fdst[, length]) seems to be a memory-efficient solution but I cannot make it work specifically with GCP (with blob).

Comment: **copyfileobj** will not help you. Unless you plan to write custom code to parse a zip file in chunks, you will need to select an instance size with enough disk space to download the zip file plus room to unzip and zip again. I am guessing you are using Cloud Functions. That is the wrong service for this problem. Compute Engine is the correct service to use.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely going to need to write some custom code for this.

I would look for a library that can take in a streaming zip data source and parse it as it streams in. It sounds like you're using Python, so that might be something like [stream-unzip](https://github.com/uktrade/stream-unzip) (haven't tried it, but it sounds like it'd solve your problem).

Then, for each of the files, as you unzip them, you need to stream them back up into Cloud Storage. There are a few ways to code that up depending on which client library you're using to write to GCS.

The code would look roughly like this:

```
def read_chunks_from_gcs(bucket, object_name):
  with your_gcs_library.read_file_like_object(bucket, object_name) as r:
    yield from r.iter_bytes(chunk_size=65536)

for file_name, file_size, unzipped_chunks in stream_unzip(read_chunks_from_gcs('mybucket', 'big-zipfile.zip'):
  stream = your_gcs_library.open_file_for_write(bucket, file_name, file_size)
  for chunk in unzipped_chunks:
    stream.write(chunk)
```

That'd probably work. If you work out an exact solution for some GCS library, I encourage you to post it as an an answer. I'd love to see what it looks like.